The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters'
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'
When I got this error,I installed the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json. Then I write namespace 'using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json;', but it showing error in '.Json' - The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Anyone have the solution for this ?
